# Put a variable into an object in R

Tags: r

Sorry about the title. I'm actually having a hard time figuring out how to even phrase the question, which is why I can't just google it.

I want to get information from a data frame in R using a variable as the column title.

```
test = data.frame(season=c('winter','summer'), temp=c('cold','hot'))
what.season = 'winter'
test$what.season
```

The third line obviously doesn't work, but what I am trying to pass it is the value of what.season so that it reads test$winter and returns 'cold'

Edit for future readers: I'm tired and I phrased it wrong, but the correct answer got at what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it

```
test[test$season == "winter", ]$temp
```

The `$` operator at the end selects to column of interest while the logical operator `==` selects the row of interest

Comment: Thanks, it makes a lot more sense to go about it this way than the way I was trying to force it. I'll set the q as answered when it allows me to.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `subset` function

```
> subset(test, season==what.season, select=temp)
  temp
1 cold
```

Comment: All of these comments are pretty good ways to go about it. I appreciate the different options.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `%in%` command

```
test$temp[test$season%in%what.season]
```

`test$season%in%what.season` will give a logical output after searching all rows (of the column `test$season`) for the values of `what.season` (winter). You can then use the logical output to filter out values from the column `test$temp`.

Answer (score 1):

The shortest way (that I know of) would be `test[test$season==what.season, 'temp']`.